# How to get number of pods (available or terminating) in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to find the number of pods currently NOT terminated (can be available, terminating, etc.) in order to prevent deployment from starting if there are still some pods not terminated.

UPDATE: If there are no pods available, I should get "0". Is it possible ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try:

`kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Succeeded,status.Phase!=Failed`

If you look at the [Pod Phases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) you can see that this covers all possible pods where all containers are terminated (either failed or succeeded)

If you specifically want the count you could use a bit of `jq` and use:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Succeeded,status.phase!=Failed --output json | jq -j '.items | length'
```

This returns the # of pods that are not `Terminated`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is it possible to get 0 when there are no pods ? when they are terminated I get "No resources found"

Comment: You mean get the number 0 when no pods are availabel instead of "No resources found"

Comment: yes, not using get pods command , but aren't there other command to see status of pods . e.g, while pods are running, with "get deployment" I can see "replicas" , but when they are in "terminating" state it's null

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to return the count.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Terminated` is not a [Pod Phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase). Where did you find that value?

Comment: You are right, I mixed up Container Statuses with Pod Statuses. I'll update the answer

Comment: There is a typo: "phase" in "status.Phase" should start with lowercase

Comment: Use the flag `--all-namespaces` to list pods from all namespaces on the cluster

Comment: As of 2023, the field selector should use `status.phase` (lowercase `P`) rather than `status.Phase`. Then this command works for me with EKS running Kubernetes 1.27

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Linux, you can use the command line tool `wc` (wordcount) to count the lines of `kubectl` (combined with the no headers option) like this:

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers | wc -l
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the `jq` answer, here is a `wc -l` answer

```sh
k3s kubectl get pods --output name | wc -l
```

This is somewhat more convenient in that `jq` may not be always installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is making sure you only have a single instance/replica of your application running at any given time, maybe it's better to rely on built-in Kubernetes options to handle that.

You can [configure your Deployment object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) using `replicas`, `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge` to control how many instances are created of your application.